# Audio/Video lag when playing through M-Audio Fast Track Pro

Tags: home-studio, audio-interfaces, m-audio

I have an M-Audio Fast Track Pro (MAFTP) running on a Windows 7 64-bit OS with an 3.4 GHz i-3 processor and 8 Gb of RAM. Yet **usually** when I run *any* sort of audio through the MAFTP I get serious lag with cracking and popping sounds. When I watch a Youtube video the video will lag as well.

This is sometimes fixed by unplugging the MAFTP and unplugging my Pro Tools MP-9 dongle, but that's becoming a less and less reliable work around. My computer is plenty fast and this happens even if I'm just playing audio through windows player.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a latency issue.
Are you using the stock windows driver?
-If so, try ASIOForAll which has a lower latency than the standard Windows driver.
You can download it for free.
In your DAW check also check the buffer size / sample rate settings in the audio configuration settings.
If the sample rate is set too low the popping & cracking is generally a symptom of this.
-Hope this helps